# Doubts on GlobalKTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am very new to Kafka Streams and I tried creating a poc to see if it suits my use case.

I have a topic in which I am producing some reference data. This data is then streamed and converted to a GlobalKTable CPK (I used a GlobalKTable as I need to join on non-keys). Once this processing is done. I then start populating another topic which then streams (SPT) the data and does an inner join on CPK to produce another GlobalKTable (JTK).

CPK and SPT are both feeds coming from an external system.

Now I have real time data coming in that I need to look up the reference data that I just populated. Let's say this stream is called "Real".  Real then does an inner join with JTK and we actually are getting good results.

Problem is when I need to delete a row from CPK. I pass a key with null value and I expect it to delete this value from CPK and the he change to also propagate to JTK. So any JTK record with that key should be deleted. But this is not happening.

Is this doable? Am I thinking in the right way? Should I use KSQL?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Did you try send message to the topic `SPT` so the join can happen and send record to `JTK`?

Comment: Yes everything is working. Only the delete is not

Comment: KSQL cannot hurt

Comment: @Sukalpo can you provide the Topology so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @cricket_007 for your suggestion. I used KSQL and everything is. working now. So basically I created a stream first by joining JTK which is now a stream (and not GKTable as earlier) with SPT. Lets name it Joined Stream. After that I create one more stream named as result by. joining Joined with CPK which is a table. (I did not find a GKTable concept in KSQL)